# Is it possible to create Terraform resource with optional attribute?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Im trying to create google_container_node_pool with autoscaling block and use either one of the following attributes:

```
min_node_count and 
max_node_count
```

OR

```
total_min_node_count and 
total_max_node_count
```

Since per zone node count (min_node_count) and total node count cannot be used simultaneously, I need some option to use this resource as a module which would then use which ever attribute/variable is given.

So for example I have 2 different environments from which one uses per zone node count and the other uses total node count. I want to be able to use this same resource as a module to avoid creating another almost the same module. If I then use this module and use min_node_count attribute, the module then should ignore total_min_node_count attribute and so on.

I dont know if this is possible, but I was struggling with this a long time and could not find a solution.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this or if its even possible without too complicated setup?

I hope I explained my problem well enough, but let me know if more details are needed

Thanks in advance

I tried something like following, but it doesnt work for obvious reasons as still autoscaling block has attribute "min_node_count" and will use any value given as value for that attribute, and does not change the attribute itself.

```
locals {
  node_pool_min_node_count = var.total_min_node_count != null ? var.total_min_node_count : var.min_node_count
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "example" {
  name       = "example-node-pool"
  location   = var.region
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.example.name

  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = local.node_pool_min_node_count
    max_node_count = same config
  }
```

Comment: You could, based on some condition, try to set any of the arguments to `null` if the condition is true/false, but it might not help. Some of the arguments are mutually exclusive and `terraform plan` will complain.

Comment: Use an if else for each value. 
min_node_count = var.x != null ? n : null

if null does not work, look up the documentation and see what the default value is.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `resource` block setting a resource-type-specific argument to `null` is exactly equivalent to leaving that argument completely unset:

```
  min_node_count = null
```

A literal `null` is not very useful, but if you ensure that your local value is `null` in cases where you don't want to set it then Terraform will interpret it as the argument not being set. Your `var.total_min_node_count` already seems to be `null` when not set, so you could just assign it directly like this:

```
  min_node_count = var.total_min_node_count
```

---

This argument belongs to the nested block `autoscaling`, and sometimes providers have validation rules that forbid leaving an argument unset inside a nested block.

If this resource type requires `min_node_count` to be set whenever an `autoscaling` block is present then you would also need to omit the declaration of the `autoscaling` block whenever the node counts would be unset.

To choose dynamically how many blocks of a particular type to generate, you can use [`dynamic` blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks). In a `dynamic` block you need to provide a `for_each` argument which is a collection that has one element per block you want to declare, so to choose between zero or one blocks you will need a collection with either zero or one elements.

The splat operator `[*]` can be applied to any non-list value that might be null to convert it automatically into a list of either zero or one elements:

- If `var.total_min_node_count` is `null` then `var.total_min_node_count[*]` is `[]`.
- If `var.total_min_node_count` is 2 then `var.total_min_node_count[*]` is `[2]`

Therefore you can use this operator to concisely use the same possibly-null input variable to decide whether to declare zero or one `autoscaling` blocks:

```
  dynamic "autoscaling" {
    for_each = var.total_min_node_count[*]
    content {
      min_node_count = autoscaling.value
    }
  }
```

`autoscaling.value` inside this block represents the value of the current element from `for_each`, so in the example above where `var.total_min_node_count[*]` produced `[2]` that would cause `autoscaling.value` to be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help! It seems that the resource/module works as follows:

```
  dynamic "autoscaling" {
    for_each = var.min_node_count != null && var.max_node_count != null ? [1] : []
    content {
      min_node_count = var.min_node_count
      max_node_count = var.max_node_count
    }
  }

  dynamic "autoscaling" {
    for_each = var.total_min_node_count != null && var.total_max_node_count != null ? [1] : []
    content {
      total_min_node_count   = var.total_min_node_count
      total_max_node_count   = var.total_max_node_count
    }
  }
```

OR simply:

```
  autoscaling {
    min_node_count       = var.min_node_count
    max_node_count       = var.max_node_count
    total_min_node_count = var.total_min_node_count
    total_max_node_count = var.total_max_node_count
  }
```

But in both cases I need to use all of the the attributes/variables when calling the module, otherwise it will result to error: "Missing required argument" which kind of defeats the puprose. However it works when I use all of them but set the variables "null" I don't want to use.

```
module "cluster" {
...
  min_node_count               = var.min_node_count # (2)
  max_node_count               = var.max_node_count # (6)
  total_min_node_count         = var.total_min_node_count # (null)
  total_max_node_count         = var.total_max_node_count # (null)
}
```

OR

```
module "cluster" {
...
  min_node_count               = var.min_node_count # (null)
  max_node_count               = var.max_node_count # (null)
  total_min_node_count         = var.total_min_node_count # (2)
  total_max_node_count         = var.total_max_node_count # (6)
}
```